# if else under for loop working on != but ==

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, if-statement, namedtuple

I'm not understanding why == condition is not working but != is working in for loop. Here's the code segment:

```
# this way it's not working . only single time running and not giving desired output

list_of_student= []

for student in student_list:

    student_detail = student(val[1],val[2],val[3])  # namedtuple

    if (student_id and student_id==student.id) or (student_name and student_name==student.name):
        return student_detail
    else:
        list_of_student.append(student_detail)
```

But if I change == to != and revert the following actions , it's working fine.
Could you please tell me the reason, or, where I'm wrong ?

```
#this way it's working fine.
list_of_student= []

for student in student_list:

    student_detail = student(val[1],val[2],val[3])   # namedtuple
    if (student_id and student_id!=student.id) or (student_name and student_name!=student.name):
        list_of_student.append(student_detail)

    else:
        return student_detail
```

Comment: WHy did you do student_id and student_id?? Why not just do `student_id == student.id`

Comment: Sure you didn't mean `student_detail.id` and `student_detail.name`?

Comment: The first check in each parenthesis was probably meant to ensure that attribute access was not done on `None` objects, in order to avoid exceptions. If indeed it is trying to avoid this, the checks should be more specific: `student_id is not None and student_id != student.id`.

Comment: I haven't uploaded the full coding, student_id is input to a fn. and we are checking with saved data in a file like student_detail.id or student.id

Comment: @tzaman , DeliriousSyntax: yeah , you are right,  it's "student_detail.name" and in actual code it's right. But for == condition neither returning the correct value nor store in list.

Answer (score 3):

To reverse the logic of a condition, you need to also replace and `and` with `or` and vice-versa, as well as negating any boolean checks, in addition to reversing the comparison operators:

```
if ((not student_id) or student_id != student.id) and ((not student_name) or student_name != student.name):
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept this answer!

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, but here what I have to do , to check student_id (a given input ) is there and if it's matching with student_detail.id (here in question i have written wrong,but main code it's ok) , then return it ,else, add the student_detail(from loop) in a list. same with student_name. Postive logic not working but  the negative one.

Comment: One more thing, request you to post in positive condition which is not working for me.

Comment: You must ask one specific thing in each question, not "help me get this entire piece of code working". I answered the specific question you asked about the difference between the two conditions; if you have additional questions, post them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You said it is stopping unexpectedly, which is because of the `return` in your for-loop, which is stopping the loop. Get rid of that and it should work (you can substitute it with `pass`).

> Source:
>   [return statement in for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864166/return-statement-in-for-loops)

Comment: yes, but if the condition fails, no use of return , right? But still it stops . Neither retrun correct value nor save in list. Please correct me , if any wrong.