# For Loop - Failing to Iterate Over Elements

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

Issue: The for loop for this function is not iterating the over all elements. Its stopping at 1. I used some diagnostic print statements to count the number of loops and its stopping at 1. I have reviewed the indentiation and the loop but cannot seem to find the issue.

```py
def process_data(data):
    """Analyzes the data, looking for maximums.

    Returns a list of lines that summarize the information.
    """
    loop_count = 0
    year_by_sales = dict()
    max_revenue = {"revenue": 0}
    # ----------->This is where the Loop Issue Exists <-----
    for item in data:
        item_price = locale.atof(item["price"].strip("$"))
        item_revenue = item["total_sales"] * item_price
        if item["car"]["car_year"] not in year_by_sales.keys():
            year_by_sales[item["car"]["car_year"]] = item["total_sales"]
            loop_count += 1
            if item_revenue > max_revenue["revenue"]:
                item["revenue"] = item_revenue
                max_revenue = item
                most_sold_model = item['car']['car_model']
                highest_total_sales = item["total_sales"]
        else:
            year_by_sales[item["car"]["car_year"]] += item["total_sales"]
            loop_count +=1 
        most_popular_year = max(year_by_sales, key=year_by_sales.get)
        summary = [
            "The {} generated the most revenue: ${}".format(
                format_car(max_revenue["car"]), max_revenue["revenue"]
            ),
            f"The {most_sold_model} had the most sales: {highest_total_sales}",
            f"The most popular year was {most_popular_year} with {highest_total_sales} sales.",
        ]
        print(loop_count)
        print(year_by_sales)
        return summary
```

## Input Data

```json
[{
        "id": 1,
        "car": {
            "car_make": "Ford",
            "car_model": "Club Wagon",
            "car_year": 1997
        },
        "price": "$5179.39",
        "total_sales": 446
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "car": {
            "car_make": "Acura",
            "car_model": "TL",
            "car_year": 2005
        },
        "price": "$14558.19",
        "total_sales": 589
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "car": {
            "car_make": "Volkswagen",
            "car_model": "Jetta",
            "car_year": 2009
        },
        "price": "$14879.11",
        "total_sales": 825
    }]
```

The entire codebase for this script is https://replit.com/join/dkuzpdujne-terry-brooksjr

Comment: Please describe what is delivered to your function as 1st argument i.e. what `data` actually is

Comment: @Daweo - Added a shortened sample od input dataq

Comment: You are returning inside the for loop. It never has a chance to loop a second time because the function returns.

Comment: I'm voting to mark this as duplicate of  [return statement in for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864166/return-statement-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually problem is that your return statement is inside the for loop so you return after the first iteration itself,
it should run just fine if you move it outside something like below:

```py
def process_data(data):
    """Analyzes the data, looking for maximums.

    Returns a list of lines that summarize the information.
    """
    loop_count = 0
    year_by_sales = dict()
    max_revenue = {"revenue": 0}
    # ----------->This is where the Loop Issue Exists <-----
    for item in data:
        item_price = locale.atof(item["price"].strip("$"))
        item_revenue = item["total_sales"] * item_price
        if item["car"]["car_year"] not in year_by_sales.keys():
            year_by_sales[item["car"]["car_year"]] = item["total_sales"]
            loop_count += 1
            if item_revenue > max_revenue["revenue"]:
                item["revenue"] = item_revenue
                max_revenue = item
                most_sold_model = item['car']['car_model']
                highest_total_sales = item["total_sales"]
        else:
            year_by_sales[item["car"]["car_year"]] += item["total_sales"]
            loop_count +=1 
        most_popular_year = max(year_by_sales, key=year_by_sales.get)
        summary = "1"

        print(loop_count)
        print(year_by_sales)
    return summary # move this out of for loop
```